# "Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память" при импорте dll с С++ в C#

Tags: c#

Код C#

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;   
 class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            { 
                uint hDll; 
                uint hObj; 
                uint Err = 0; 
                string s = "lcomp.dll"; 
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!!!"); 
                hDll = wlcomp.LoadAPIDLL(s); 
                Console.WriteLine(hDll.ToString()); 
                hObj = wlcomp.CallCreateInstance(ref hDll, 1, ref Err); 
                Console.WriteLine(hObj.ToString()); 
                Console.WriteLine(Err.ToString());
                wlcomp.OpenLDevice(ref hObj); 
          }
        static class wlcomp
        {
            public static uint L_STREAM_ADC = 1;
            [DllImport("wlcomp.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern uint LoadAPIDLL(string dllname);
            [DllImport("wlcomp.dll")]
            public static extern uint FreeAPIDLL(ref uint hDll);
            [DllImport("wlcomp.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern uint CallCreateInstance(ref uint hDll, uint slot, ref uint Err);
            [DllImport("wlcomp.dll")]
            public static extern uint PlataTest(ref uint hIfc);
            [DllImport("wlcomp.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
            public static extern uint OpenLDevice(ref uint hIfc);
    }
```

Кусок dll:

```
DllExport(ULONG) OpenLDevice(PULONG hIfc)
{
   return (ULONG)(((IDaqLDevice*)*hIfc)->OpenLDevice());
}
```

В `OpenLDevice` вылетает `AccessViolationException` и говорит: "Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена."

Как лечить?

Comment: Вы наверняка неправильно прописали сигнатуры P/Invoke. Перепроверьте.

Comment: Например, почему вы под указатель выделяете `uint`, а не `IntPtr`? Подумайте, что произойдёт на 64-битной платформе.